# Find pages from orders of a specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following associations:

```
User has_many Order
Order has_many Pages
```

How can I find all the pages that belongs to a specific User? Is not a directly association, but the table Order is between them. So, I can't do:

```
user.pages
```

I just can do `user.orders`

Comment: Hommer, did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably a different association. Try the has_many :through association.

```
User.rb
has_many :orders
has_many :pages, through: :orders

Order.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :page

Page.rb
has_many :orders
has_many :users, through: :orders
```

Take a look at the Rails documentation for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

If you don't really need more metadata on the joining model (in this case, Order.rb), you can simply also use a HABTM association.

- Generate a table called users_pages

and then:

```
User.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :pages

Pages.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

For more information on this association read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

For more information on when to choose either, read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many